# How to access a "generated application controller"? in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my HTML file I have:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    //some code
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Which has been working as my layout for all templates, but this doesn't have any controller made by me so Ember generates one.

My question is how to access the controller for this handlebar?

*The generated application controller* 
on the [official documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/the-application-template/) says:

> The *application* template is the default template that is rendered when
>   your application starts.

This is what I want to be able to access. What I really want to do is just add to it:

```
needs: ['someController']
```

PS: After looking for a bit I tried making a file "`application.js`" on the controllers folder but it doesn't seem this is it.

Comment: Need some details. (1) Did you miss the template name in the script tag on purpose? (2) You said `how to access the controller for this handlebar` and later you said `The application template bla bla This is what I want to be able to access`. Can't get it completely

Comment: I may have some notions confused seen as I'm new to Ember, but what I want is to access the controller of the default template that is rendered when my application starts (if that even exists or is accessible).

Comment: Really sorry guys it seems that what I was looking for really was the application.js file on the controllers folder and I just forgot to include it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    //some code
    {{outlet}}
</script>
```

This script defines your application's main template inside your HTML. Usually you need to name your scripts, but this is not necessary for the `Application/index` - see it in the [documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/handlebars-basics/#toc_defining-templates).

Also from the documentation: "By default, your top-most application template is bound to your ApplicationController:"

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({});
```

So if you need to customize something for the application, instead of using the autogenerated controller, you must create an explicit one; there you can add `needs: ['someController']`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I think what you're looking for really is making an application.js file in the controllers folder like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['someController'],
});
```

and don't forget to include it in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your `application.js` and your `route.js` files with a simple `IndexRoute`.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
    }
});
```

and replace your `{{outlet}}` with a template

```
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>{{item}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Look at this beginner example: [http://emberjs.jsbin.com/koziwatacu/1/edit](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/koziwatacu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Official documentation: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/the-application-template/

Comment: This doens't seem to be what I want.